# CSS drop-down menu not fully displayed

Tags: css, drop-down-menu

I'm designing a Homepage like this: https://dl.dropboxusercontent.com/u/178536659/new/Document.htm and I'm currently working on the **dropdown menu**. *My problem is that my dropdown menu is not fully displayed.* I tried so many ways such as using *"float: left"* (what what I'm using now) or using *"dislay:inline"* for the `ul li`, it still doesn't work.

Answer (score 0, accepted):

try this

in this class #nav li ul `z-index` give then menu show properly,

```
 #nav li ul {
    background-color: black;
    display: none;
    left: -60px;
    margin: 0;
    padding: 0;
    position: absolute;
    width: 257px;
    z-index: 1;
}

#nav ul li ul li {
    border-bottom: 2px solid #2185C5;
    padding: 14px;
    width: 89%;
}
```

Comment: Fags is right. Also, you should clear the float on the #content div, to do so add overflow: hidden to it or add a proper clear float class.

Comment: Thanks. Can anyone tell me how to remove the black blank in the dropdown menu (before "PRO EVOLUTION SOCCER" for example)

Comment: Tks, but I mean whatever background color i set for class #nav li ul; it left a small blank with that color before my sub item in dropdown menu and I don't know how to remove that blank

Comment: check my answer now i update, in this #nav li ul class give  left:-49px;

Comment: i tried and it's look like this: https://dl.dropboxusercontent.com/u/178536659/new/Document.htm. Hope you can help fix it more good looking :(

Comment: #nav li ul {
    background-color: black;
    display: none;
    left: -60px;
    margin: 0;
    padding: 0;
    position: absolute;
    width: 257px;
    z-index: 1;
}

#nav ul li ul li {
    border-bottom: 2px solid #2185C5;
    padding: 14px;
    width: 89%;
}  now try this my answer update your solution be done

Answer (score 0):

Add the following to remove the extra blue border:

```
#nav ul li ul li {
padding: 14px 25px 14px 14px;
border-bottom: 2px solid #2185C5;
width: 100%;
margin-left: -40px;
}

#aftercolor {
position: absolute;
top: 99px;
height: 8px;
width: 960px;
background-color: #2185C5;
}
```

also add `margin:0` to your `body` to make your site good looking.

```
body{
margin: 0;
}
```